# XCode - move target to a different project

Tags: xcode, frameworks

I have created an Xcode project and that contains an app and a framework. I would like to move the framework out to a different project.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Figured it out... Just create a new project and moved the files across.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out... Just create a new project and moved the files across, then deleted that target in the old project

Comment: Good to know that it's a relatively pain-free process...!